# how can we pass a list of items to scrapy pipeline?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

i have written a spider which after creating and inserting scraped data appending it to a list of items,

```
items = []
item1=ScrapedItem()
item1['x']='xxx'
items.append(item1)

item2=ScrappedItem()
item2['x']='aaa'
items.append(item2)
return items         #returning a list not a single item to scrapy pipeline
```

now i want to write a pipeline which can take a list and not a single item object, so that my pipeline is get called just once

any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure you can get scrapy to call you pipeline just once, but in  `process_item(self, item, spider):`  you could simply append your items one at a time in a list (that you would have created in your pipeline's `__init__()`) and process all items in the list in `close_spider()`

Comment: is it true?, that a spider class `parse(self, response)` function gets called multiple times and response parameter is created only once that is passed into this parse function, could be a separate question but related somehow..i dont want this response object get created multiple times

Comment: To my knowledge, `parse()` is called only once per response, and response object is created only once

Comment: +1 thanks... your suggestions helped. although we can pass a list of items to a pipeline the way i have written in my question... somehow scrapy pipeline is iterating over list.